# Component being rendered 6 times in react

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I am trying to use a custom hook to call the API for fetching data. And then I am trying to call that hook in my Context API. The problem is that the body of the hook is being rendered 6 times. So then when I try to setState in my Context file using the data returned by the custom hook(useFetchData), I get the error - "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.". I think some state change is causing it to re-render.

context.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import useFetchData from './Custom Hooks/useFetchData'

export const Context = createContext();

export function Provider(props) {
  let intialState = {
    track_list: [],
    heading: "",
    loading: true
    // dispatch: action => this.setState(state => reducer(state, action))
  };

  const [state, setState] = useState(intialState)

  // Get Top 10 Tracks
  const url = 'chart.tracks.get?chart_name=top&page=1&page_size=5&country=it&f_has_lyrics=1'
  const [data, loading] = useFetchData(url)
  // setState({ track_list: data, heading: "Top 10 Tracks", loading })  // Causes Too Many Re-renders.
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[state, setState]}>{props.children}</Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

useFetchData (Custom Hook)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function useFetchData(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  console.log('Rendering Again and Again');
  useEffect(() => {
    // Top 10 Tracks
    async function fetchData(url) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `${url}&apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
        );
        const data = await response.data.message.body;
        console.log(data);
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    fetchData(url);
  }, [url]);

  return [data, loading];
}

export default useFetchData;
```

Browser Logs

useFetchData.js:7 Rendering Again and Again

useFetchData.js:7 Rendering Again and Again

useFetchData.js:16 {track_list: Array(5)}

useFetchData.js:7 Rendering Again and Again

useFetchData.js:7 Rendering Again and Again

useFetchData.js:7 Rendering Again and Again

useFetchData.js:7 Rendering Again and Again

[Error When I uncomment {// setState({ track_list: data, heading: "Top 10 Tracks", loading })  // Causes Too Many Re-renders.} this line in context file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gJcx.png)

Answer (score 3):

`setState({ track_list: data, heading: "Top 10 Tracks", loading })` is causing an infinite number of re-renders because you're setting it in the body of the component, not in response to something, e.g., a handler or an effect. So, each time through you're setting state, which results in a render, which then re-sets state, causing another render, ad infinitum.

Add a `useEffect` in your provider to detect changes to the relevant data and set the state there. Something like,

```
useEffect(() => {
    setState({ track_list: data, heading: "Top 10 Tracks", loading })
}, [loading, data])
```

This will only be called when `loading` or `data` is different than the last render.

Comment: I can avoid the infinite loop now, but I get a lot of log statements. First the state is empty and then some of it populated and then all of the data is populated, this is a problem as the components who are using the state from the context are getting empty state.

Comment: @VaasuDhand that's just how react works. Components will render as many times as they need to, depending on state changes, props, etc. You can wrap components in conditionals `{!Boolean(someState) ? <MyComponent /> : 'Loading...' }` if you want to show them when a piece of state is a certain value or not null/undefined.